# Swift parse dictionary with guard statements

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

A JSON call returns a dictionary, as below. Either of the two values, or the "secondLevel" dictionary itself, may be missing.

```
{
   "theMain" : {
      "secondLevel" : {
         "value1" : "5.3",
         "value2" : "bbb"
      }
   }
}
```

I'm parsing with guard statements:

```
guard let main = theJson["theMain"] as? [String : Any] else {
    return
}
guard let second = main["secondLevel"] as? [String : Any] else {
    let second = [String : Any]()
}
guard second.count > 0,
    let firstValue = second["value1"] as? String else {
        let firstValue = "n/a"
}
guard second.count > 0,
    let secondValue = second["value2"] as? String else {
        let secondValue = "n/a"
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want a per-field error handling procedure, then no. If it's admissible to have a shared error handling procedure (e.g. returning `nil` from a bailable initializer), then all the guard statements can be combined.

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use **one** guard statement for checking the keys `theMain`, `secondLevel` and if the number of items in `secondLevel` dictionary is > 0.

Since the `secondLevel` dictionary contains only string values, cast it to `[String : String]` which avoids further down casting.

Finally use the nil-coalescing operator to assign n/a if the key is missing.

```
guard let main = theJson["theMain"] as? [String : Any], 
      let second = main["secondLevel"] as? [String : String], !second.isEmpty {
        return
}

let firstValue = second["value1"] ?? "n/a"
let secondValue = second["value2"] ?? "n/a"
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for my uses, since if `second` is empty, I still want the two values to be `"n/a"`. Still, some great info for me! (improving the casting, the null coalescing operator, and dictionary.isEmpty shortcut)

Comment: I'm afraid your example code does not assign `n/a` to the two values either if `second` is empty. `guard second.count > 0` skips the code in the following braces if the condition is true. To get `n/a` if `second` is empty just remove the last check `, !second.isEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the excellent ideas from @vadian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40231601/383919), especially the [nil coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#Swift) and the better casting, this is what worked for me:

```
guard let main = incoming["theMain"] as? [String : Any] else {
    return
}
let second = main["secondLevel"] as? [String : String] ?? [String : String]()
let firstValue = second["value1"] ?? "n/a"
let secondValue = second["value2"] ?? "n/a"
```